# *_set attributes on models from different Apps

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models defined in different Apps, related by a Many to Many relationship:

```
#App 1, models.py

class Parent(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_lenght=10)
```

```
#App2, models.py
from App1.models import Parent

class Child(models.Model):
    parents = models.ManyToManyField(
        to = Parent,
        blank = True,
        default = None,
        related_name = 'padres'
    )
```

I would like to access the Child element from the Parent Model. When Models are in the same app, you can just do child_set, but in this case, it is not defined. **Is there anyway to do it?**

I can't define the M2M relationship in Parent because I'm importing other models from App1 in App2, and doing so would lead to a circular importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have set related name in your Child model, the following code should do it-

```
parents=get_object_or_404(Parent, id=2)
childs=parents.padres.all()
```